# RigidBody прилипает к стенам

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Пытаюсь реализовать 3D-передвижение а-ля Titanfall. Решил использовать RigidBody с AddForce (по каким-то своим внутренним усмотрениям), но уперся в проблему со стенами: когда персонаж прислоняется к препядствию, он абсолютно не двигается вдоль него и идет только в обратном от преграды направлении (не обязательно перпендикулярно, но все же). Эта проблема решается с добавлением кастомного Physic material с нулевым трением, но тогда возникает другая загвоздка: из-за отсутсвия трения спокойно встать на таком препядствии невозможно.

```
public class MovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float maxSpeed;
    public float sprintMult;

    public float jumpForce;
    public Transform playerBody;
    public Rigidbody rigidBody;

    private float xMove = 0;
    private float yMove = 0;
    private float zMove = 0;
    private Vector3 move = new Vector3(0, 0);

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        xMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        yMove = rigidBody.velocity.y;
        zMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rigidBody.AddForce(new Vector3(0, jumpForce, 0), ForceMode.Impulse);
            Debug.Log("Jump");
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)) maxSpeed *= sprintMult;
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift)) maxSpeed /= sprintMult;

        move = playerBody.forward * zMove + playerBody.right * xMove;
        move *= speed * Time.deltaTime;

        rigidBody.AddForce(move, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        rigidBody.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(rigidBody.velocity, maxSpeed);
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(rigidBody.velocity.x, yMove, rigidBody.velocity.z);

        //Debug.Log(xMove + ", " + zMove + ", " + rigidbody.velocity + ": " + rigidbody.velocity.magnitude);
    }
}
```

Вроде слышал, что Character controller таких проблем не знает, но боюсь, что для бега по стенам, подкатов и, в особенности, манипуляций с ускорением (постепенный разгон/остановка, рывок и тд) такой способ передвижения объектов плохо приспособлен.